# Using awk to modify 3rd Column values

Tags: awk

I am trying to convert the 3rd column as shown below. I can use this function to

```
convert ***awk '{print $3}'  | awk -F: '{printf("%02s:%02s:%02s:%02s:%02s:%02s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)}'*** but how to get it to replace the 3rd column values.

Before 

ABC    22.22.28.97     0:0:c:9f:f0:d9

ABC    22.22.28.109    0:50:56:64:49:f3

ABC    22.22.28.110    0:50:56:68:55:8e

After

ABC    22.22.28.97     00:00:0c:9f:f0:d9

ABC    22.22.28.109    00:50:56:64:49:f3

ABC    22.22.28.110    00:50:56:68:55:8e
```

Thank you :)

Comment: I tried to replay your command line: `convert ***awk '{print $3}' `  but I get an error: convert: unable to open image. Please tell me the exact command that you are giving.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're asking is how to zero-pad the hexadecimal elements of the colon-separated string in the third field. That's (perhaps surprisingly) hard to do in `awk` because:

1. the `%s` (string) format specifier doesn't support zero-padding (neither in `awk` nor in the underlying C function AFAIK)

and

2. if you use the appropriate numeric format `%02x` then the arguments are implicitly converted *as decimal digits* first (discarding a-f as garbage) - resulting in incorrect hexadecimal values.

If you have GNU awk, you can manipulate and convert hex digits using the `--non-decimal-data` command line option, however the elements themselves need to be prefixed with `0x` to force the conversion. So for example

```
gawk --non-decimal-data '
  gsub(/[[:xdigit:]][[:xdigit:]]?/,"0x&",$3) && split($3,a,":") {
    $3=sprintf("%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6])
  } 1' OFS='\t' file
ABC     22.22.28.97     00:00:0c:9f:f0:d9

ABC     22.22.28.109    00:50:56:64:49:f3

ABC     22.22.28.110    00:50:56:68:55:8e
```

It's somewhat simpler in `perl` where you can use the `hex` function and simple regex substitution:

```
perl -alne '$F[2] =~ s/([[:xdigit:]]{1,2})/sprintf "%02x", hex($1)/ge , print join "\t", @F' file
ABC     22.22.28.97     00:00:0c:9f:f0:d9

ABC     22.22.28.109    00:50:56:64:49:f3

ABC     22.22.28.110    00:50:56:68:55:8e
```

Comment: I found an easier answer sed 's/\b\(\w\)\b/0\1/g'  file to work \b(between a word character and a non-word character). Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier answer 's/\b(\w)\b/0\1/g' file. I want to use awk but sed has the \b (between a word character and a non-word character)

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/\b([0-9a-f](:|$))/0$1/g' ex
```

- add a `0` before all the singular hexdecimal digits followed by ":" or end of line